# How Can I Reset a Gameobject which was under DontDestroyLoad?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the following script in a separate scene to keep my object "player"(it's a car) and load another scene.

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
```

but in my game, the state of car will be changed like its speed, indicator, the level of getting hit.

i wanna reset the status of this car to the original status when I click the button Restart Game.

Is there any way I can do to reset the car apart from destroying the car and switching back to the original scene to execute DontDestroyOnLoad again?

Comment: What if you change the values via. GetComponent() after you switched the scenes?

Comment: Use a Singleton pattern and store the reference somewhere `static` so you can easily access it. Or actually if the only purpose of that script is storing values and actually has no kind of behavior on its own than rather directly use a `static class` that's doesn't need to be bound to any GameObject and simply lives forever

Comment: Thank you so much, i found a singleton pattern works for me!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you have public variables set to user defined values and you would like these to be the initial ones which was assigned by the user when you reload your initial scene. There are two solutions for this:

**(a)** Destroy the DontDestroyOnLoad gameObject so that when you reload the initial scene, a new instance of this will be created, hence your user defined values will be retained. So when you want to reload to initial scene from the end scene, create a script and add these:

```
Destroy (GameObject.Find("NameOfTheGameObject"));
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
```

**(b)** Retain the car and its script, instead create another script and copy the initial values to the second script. For example, attach the below code to a new script and attach that script to your car gameObject:

**Script 1 - DontDestroyOnLoad**

```
public int Acceleration_Of_Car = 20;
public int Car_Force = 100;

public static ClassNameHere instance;
 
 void Awake()
 {
      if(instance == null)
      {
           instance = this;
           DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
      }else if(instance != this)
      {
           Destroy(gameObject);
      }
 }
```

Now create second script in the End Scene or even in the Initial Scene. Create variables that are the same as first script so that you do not get confused. Copy values from first script to second script, later apply values from second script to first script.

**Script 2 - Copy and Apply**

```
public int Acceleration_Of_Car;
public int Car_Force;

private Script1 script1; //Reference your first script here
public void Start()
{
   script1 = (Script1) GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(Script1)); //Call the first script
}

public void CopyValues()
{
  Acceleration_Of_Car = script1.Acceleration_Of_Car;
  Car_Force = script1.Car_Force;
}

public void ApplyValues()
{
 script1.Acceleration_Of_Car = Acceleration_Of_Car;
 script1.Car_Force = Car_Force;
}
```

I would say its better to use DontDestroyOnLoad() even for second script so that no other instance will be running :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Destroy(GameObject.Find("GameObjectName"));
    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneIndex);
```